# Pip defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

Tags: python, selenium

I have downloaded selenium on Windows 10 but when I run my program I receive this error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'`. I have tried reinstalling the packet but I am told that `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable` and my requirement is already satisfied. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: Did you add the user-installed package directory to your PYTHONPATH?